# Object Required error while calling function

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting this error when I try to call the function addSimpleBordersToAllSidesOfRange.
Calling catSheet works pretty well on other parts of the code, but when I get to this line where I call this function, the error is thrown.
I actually wanted to pass the following values to it

```
Dim catSheet As Worksheet
    Set catSheet = seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt(CStr(cat), prodSoldByCatMonthlyWb)
    addSimpleBordersToAllSidesOfRange (catSheet.range("a1:c2"))
```

I've tried this just to see what would happen, but got the same error:

`addSimpleBordersToAllSidesOfRange (range("A2"))`

Function:

```
Public Function addSimpleBordersToAllSidesOfRange(ByRef range2 As range)
     With range2
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = x1LineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = x1LineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = x1LineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = x1LineStyle.xlContinuous
     End With
End Function
```

Comment: Functions return values, they would no format cells.

Comment: try changing it to a sub and `Call`ing it

Comment: `x1LineStyle` ----> `xlLineStyle`. The letter `l` as in `Lima`.

Comment: Remove the parentheses around `catSheet.range("a1:c2")`

Comment: @Davesexcel technically a `Function` can format a cell but I agree with changing this to a `Sub`. The problem though is the parentheses around the argument.

Comment: one line to border all `range2.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous`